# cognito Oauth2.0 third party authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, amazon-cognito

Hello I'm currently using aws cognito for authentication and authorization.

I want to add a 3rd party identity provider that only supports OAuth not OIDC.

Is it possible to add authentication with this identity provider without OIDC?

Thank you.